# Alert in azure topic grafana doesboard do not working

Tags: azureservicebus, grafana-alerts

I am using grafana with a plugin named Azure monitor in a panel that get information about Azure topic.

https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/azure-monitor/

In my panel I see the actives messages and the messages in the dead letter queue.

Up to this point everything is ok, the panel works correctly.

I have a problem trying to create an alert on this panel.

I need to create an alert that tells me when there is a message in the dead letter queue.

However the alert is executed when the dead letter queue is empty:

Value: [ var='Alert stock transfers0' metric='Count of dead-lettered messages in a Queue/Topic.' labels={EntityName=stock-transfer} value=360 ], [ var='Alert stock transfers1' metric='Count of active messages in a Queue/Topic.' labels={EntityName=stock-transfer} value=360 ]

[image]

This is the expresion used in grafana:

[image]

Does anyone have any idea what might be going on?

Thank you!